# c# How do I use this function on a file

Tags: c#

Sorry if the title may be misleading, but I have created a decoder in c#, but how do I use the function on (save.dat (the game save)) it needs to be loaded in a byte array.

Code for the decoder: https://del.dog/sorononami

Sorry I'm a starter in c#.

I have tried but I got this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ConsoleApp8.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ConsoleApp8.Program.PwDecLol(Byte[] lel) in C:\repos\ConsoleApp8\ConsoleApp8\Program.cs:line 180
   at ConsoleApp8.Program..cctor() in C:\repos\ConsoleApp8\ConsoleApp8\Program.cs:line 183
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ConsoleApp8.Program.Main() in C:\repos\ConsoleApp8\ConsoleApp8\Program.cs:line 15
```

Looks like I am not doing it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's anything wrong with your decoder. The error message suggests you have a parameter in the constructor to your program, which the runtime doesn't know how to resolve.

Try removing any parameters from the main entry point into your programs (except string[] args).

Alternatively, post the code from your program's entry point.

Comment: yeah the decoder is file. but i do not know how to load the save.dat. Do i load it in byte[] or string[]

Comment: The simplest way to read the bytes of a file is `byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("C:\some path\file.dat");`

Comment: tried this already gives the same issue ig thanks for the help tho

Comment: Can you post your constructor (around line 183 in Program.cs)

Comment: https://del.dog/rexutecycy and then I print it out in the console

Comment: You should use the full file path. I'm guessing here, but it's probably something like "C:\repos\ConsoleApp8\ConsoleApp8\save.dat"

Comment: i did try that aswell oof

Comment: Try taking the code out of static variables and load them in your entrypoint. Something like `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(..); string message = PwDecLol(bytes)...;`

Comment: Hmm.. Can you post the full method where you are doing this.

Comment: "save.dat" still isn't the full file path?

Comment: ```byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\repos\ConsoleApp8\ConsoleApp8\bin\Release\save.dat");``` Same exception

Comment: Hey I have removed try catch stuff and now this is happening https://del.dog/cimocowodu

Comment: Ah, that's a useful development, and a good example of not having giant try-catch blocks. Do you understand why and where this is happening?

Comment: maybe here: ```string message = PwDecLol(bytes).Aggregate("", (current, str) => current + str + Environment.NewLine);``` but what to do no idea

Comment: I'm assuming you're German, given your username? Is your computer's locale set to German? I think your computer might be having issues with parsing doubles with a full stop. It's probably expecting `double.Parse("1,23")` instead of `double.Parse("1.23")`. Firstly, you can use the literal `1.23` instead of `double.Parse("1.23")`. Secondly, if you need to use `double.Parse`, then pass in an invariant culture if parsing numbers with full stops.

Comment: I did invariant culture. Got a cast issue fixed it with ```      int num1 = 0;
      foreach (int num2 in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(A_1))
        num1 += num2;
``` instead of ```int num1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(A_1).Cast<int>().Sum();``` still getting: https://del.dog/cimocowodu

Comment: Try `.Select(x => (int)x)` instead of `.Cast<int>()`

Comment: Okay looks like i missed 1 invariant culture. Now the application works. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you got there in the end!